# How does JSON.parse() do its thing?

Tags: javascript, php, json, parsing

So... I am trying to use JavaScript to parse an object returned from an PHP file. The relevant code looks like this:

```
var name = document.getElementBId("name").value;
var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
XHR.open("GET', 'lookup.php?name=' + name, true);

XHR.onreadystatechange = function (){
    try{
        alert("Attempting to parse");
        if ((XHR.readyState === 4) && (XHR.status === 200)) {
            alert("Parsing");
            var jsonresponse = JSON.parse(XHR.responseText);
            alert("Is this being skipped?");
        ....
```

Here's the php being returned:

```
{
  "name": ABC Elementary, 
  "addr": 3000 County Road 29 Alberta AL 36720-2817, 
  "county": Wilcox, "district": 6;
}
```

This program is supposed to submit a school's name for a math tournament and use the rest of that info to display the school's address, county, and district once its name has been selected. I picked ABC Elementary as the debugger because it's easy to type.

Unfortunately, the script won't proceed past this point. I'm getting an alert from the `alert("Parsing")`, but not from `alert("Is this being skipped?")`. I'm also not getting anything past that point within the `XML.onreadystatechange()`, although I am still getting alerts from outside the block.

My guess is that it has something to do with how `JSON.parse()` handles data, or at least it has to do with that line.

Also, I know that other people have asked about this, and I have been looking for these answers, but nobody seems interested in knowing what exactly `JSON.parse()` is doing to that data. If anyone could enlighten me, I would be very grateful.

Comment: use json_encode() in php, don't hand-build your JSON

Comment: Open your browser's developer console to see the error you're getting. Your data isn't valid JSON.

Comment: ABC Elementary -> "ABC Elementary"  and 3000 County Road 29 Alberta AL 36720-2817 -> "3000 County Road 29 Alberta AL 36720-2817" and you have more, as written in other comments. And do use a library for your Ajax. This is not cross browser what you have

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to mention that this code is being uploaded to a machine that does not understand json_encode(), or I would have used that. I did open the browser's console to check for errors, but it didn't return any, even though it clearly isn't working.

@ItayMoav-Malimovka I understand your concern there. Cross-browser compatibility is definitely an important thing, but it's not a concern here. Although, if you can point me to a good reference to learn more about AJAX libraries, I certainly wouldn't complain :)

Comment: jQuery is the most common such library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, JSON.parse() takes a **string value**, a stringified object  and parses it.

For JSON.parse() to work for your case, we want the object returned to be:

```
{"name": "ABC Elementary", "addr": "3000 County Road 29 Alberta AL 36720-2817", "county": "Wilcox", "district": "6"}
```

...BUT we want that wrapped in a string as the input for parse.

Add this line to your console and press enter and you will see the result of the parse:

```
JSON.parse('{"name": "ABC Elementary", "addr": "3000 County Road 29 Alberta AL 36720-2817", "county": "Wilcox", "district": "6"}');
```

For more information, you can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) that might be able to explain it better.

Comment: Alright! I changed my php up a little, so now it returns strings in the format you gave, and the code runs now! Now... I'm still a little iffy on exactly what it means to parse an object. As far as I can tell, it just takes that string and... uses it to build another object? That seems to be what happened here, but I'm not sure if there's anything else going on that I just don't see.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "name": ABC Elementary, 
  "addr": 3000 County Road 29 Alberta AL 36720-2817, 
  "county": Wilcox, "district": 6; /* the ; here must delete */
}
```

if this is your json string. it is wrong in format(see comment above)

you can use alert(xhr.responseText) or console.log(xhr.responseText) to make sure you get the json

string you want.

open your browser debug tool to check the console message,

if you are using old browsers do not support JSON.parse

you can read here

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON#Browser_compatibility

and

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js